# Autolack – Metallic oder auch nicht

Tags: single-word-request

Wie nennt man einen Lack, der nicht metallic ist … Ist das dann ein Normallack oder Unmetalliclack, Nichtmetalliclack oder was weiß ich?

Comment: Hölzern, mehlig, erdig, pastell und v.a. matt.

Comment: @userunknown Lack, der nicht metallic ist, ist aber nicht zwangsläufig auch matt...

Comment: @userunknown „Matte“ Lackierungen sind bei Autos relativ neu und kosten i.d.R. einen höheren Aufpreis als Sonderfarben (Uni), Metallic oder Perleffekt.

Comment: Ist 'mehlig' am Ende auch nicht ganz richti? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin nicht sicher, ob das ein Standardbegriff ist, aber für "nicht-metallic-Lackierungen" findet sich beispielsweise in den Konfiguratoren von Skoda und VW online der Begriff "Uni-Lackierung".

Es ergibt aus meiner Sicht auch Sinn von einer "einfarbigen" (im Sinne von "nicht gemusterten") Lackierung zu sprechen, da sich beim Metallic-Lack ja eine gewisse Musterung ergibt, welche beim Uni-Lack nicht vorhanden ist.

---

Bitte beachte auch die von SteffPoint verlinkte [Seite](http://www.autolack21.de/lackier-praxis/lackier-wegweiser/artikel-lackier-wegweiser/wegweiser-farbe-einschicht-oder-zweischicht-system-uni-oder-metallic.html) - hier wird das definiert und erklärt. Ich wollte den Link auch einfügen, SteffPoint war etwas schneller :-D

Comment: Das Gegenteil einer einfarbigen Lackierung wäre meiner Meinung nach eine mehrfarbige Lackierung, also eine Lackierung mit mehreren (mindestens zwei) unterschiedlich gefärbten Lacken, die nebeneinander auf dasselbe Werkstück aufgetragen werden. Wenn aber das Gegenteil einer mehrfarbigen Lackierung eine einfarbige Lackierung ist, dann tut sich die einfarbige Lackierung schwer, gleichzeitig auch das Gegenteil von etwas ganz anderem zu sein.

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort erweitert um die Tatsache, das "Uni" sich nicht zwangsläufig auf die Farbe, sondern vor allem auf das Muster bezieht. Etwas, das "uni" ist, ist nicht gemustert. Ich hoffe, es wird dadurch klarer.

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde es als Normallack betiteln. Unilack/Klarlack sind verschiedene Lackarten, die du als Normallack bezeichnen kannst. Ein Standard, welcher Lack verwendet wird, ist nirgens normiert, deswegen sollte die Bezeichnung des „Gegenteils“ so objektiv wie möglich sein.

Weitere nützliche Informationen kannst du auf [dieser Seite](http://www.autolack21.de/lackier-praxis/lackier-wegweiser/artikel-lackier-wegweiser/wegweiser-farbe-einschicht-oder-zweischicht-system-uni-oder-metallic.html) finden.